# How to query duplicated rows according to column value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate my rows based on the pass and fail column. Below is the table that I've done querying so far.

[image]

The code for the query is shown below. I'm querying from a json.

```
SELECT
    to_date(LotSummary ->> 'Start', 'HH24:MI:SS DD/MM/YY')AS "Date",
    Machine AS "Machine",
    LotSummary ->> 'Pass' AS "Pass",
    LotSummary ->> 'Fail' AS "Fail"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN jsonb_typeof(json_data->'OEESummary'->'LotSummary'->'Lot') = 'array'
            THEN
                jsonb_array_elements(cast(json_data->'OEESummary'->'LotSummary'->'Lot' AS JSONB))
            ELSE
                json_data->'OEESummary'->'LotSummary'->'Lot'
            END
        AS LotSummary,
        json_data->'OEESummary'->>'MachineID' AS Machine
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        jsonb_array_elements(cast(json_data->>'body' AS JSONB)) AS json_data
      FROM data
    )t
    WHERE
       json_data ->> 'file_name' = 'OEE.xml'
)a
WHERE
    to_date(LotSummary ->> 'Start', 'HH24:MI:SS DD/MM/YY') IS NOT NULL
```

So let's say I want to query it as duplicates to separate **Pass** and **Fail** values just like:

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+------+
|            Date            |   Machine    | Pass | Fail |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+------+
| "2019-08-04T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-082 | 5    | NULL |
| "2019-08-04T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-082 | NULL | 2    |
| "2019-07-01T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-001 | 0    | NULL |
| "2019-07-01T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-001 | NULL | 0    |
| "2019-07-01T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-001 | 20   | NULL |
| "2019-07-01T16:00:00.000Z" | TRS1000i-001 | NULL | 0    |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+------+
```

Just in case you need the json formats (Do note it's not the exact one, but the format is correct):

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "file_name": "OEE.xml",
      "OEESummary": {
        "MachineID": "TRS1000i-012",
        "LotSummary": {
          "Lot": [
            {
              "@i": "0",
              "Start": "14:52:16 15/08/19",
              "Pass": "3",
              "Fail": "0"
            },
            {
              "@i": "1",
              "Start": "15:40:41 15/08/19",
              "Pass": "3",
              "Fail": "0"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Utilisation": [
          "0:01:42:48",
          "19.04%"
        ],
        "MTTR": "--",
        "IdleTime": "0:07:16:39",
        "MUBA": "57",
        "OEE": "60.55%"
      }
    }
  ],
  "header": {
    "json_metadata_revision": "v1.0.0",
    "json_metadata_datetime_creation": "14-OCT-2019_14:55:57",
    "json_metadata_uuid": "14102019145557_65b425d8-09e5-48ec-be85-e69d9a50d2e3",
    "json_metadata_type": "mvst_xml_to_json"
  }
}
```

Do help if you know any techniques I could use to solve this issue. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank youu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your table, you can use a lateral join:

```
select t.date, t.machine, v.pass, v.fail
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.pass, null), (null, t.fail)) v(pass, fail);
```

I'm not quite sure what your query has to do with the question.  But you can define it as a CTE and then use the results for `t`.

Comment: Ya, I think my title is a little misleading, it should be "Select rows into duplicates based on column values." Anyways, you got my point right. I'll take some time trying this out but I think it'll work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the top of your result set , its just union query:

```
  WITH A AS(
  Select 1 id , 'TRS1000i-082' as Machine    , 5 pass, 2 fail union all
  Select 2 id , 'TRS1000i-001' as Machine    , 0 pass, 0 fail union all
  Select 3 id , 'TRS1000i-001' as Machine    , 20 pass, 0 fail 
  )
  SELECT ID
     ,MACHINE
     ,pass
     ,null fail
  FROM a
UNION ALL
  SELECT ID
     ,MACHINE
     ,null pass
     ,fail fail
  FROM a
  order by ID
```

Comment: Works too. Thank you!